# How to deploy a server to connect to the database

Tags: c#, winforms

Have a program on winforms, where so far there is only an authorization window, there are two textBox, where you enter the username and password respectively, there is a local server deployed through mamp, as well as a database of mysql, to which the connection is made, the database has one table users, which contains three fields - id, login and password, which should add new users through, not yet made, registration form, while there is one test field to check the success of authorization. The question is whether you can somehow deploy a server on your PC to be able to connect to the database on my PC through another PC, through my application, and check the success of authorization?

So far, no ideas, the only thing I assume is that you need to buy hosting and there is already on the server to add a database, get a new line of connection from the hosting and then you can work. But since the project is a test one, I would not want to spend money on hosting yet.I'm new to this topic, and I don't really understand how it all works yet, I'd be happy to get any ideas.

Comment: The question is kind of all over the place, but are you just looking to host a server application on your computer which other computers can connect to?  An ASP.NET Web API project can serve that purpose.  Your WinForms app can also serve that purpose, manually listening on a port or socket depending on how you want clients to connect to it.  Once your application is running and listening for connections, any client application can connect to it.  (Barring firewalls or other network blockages, which is another concern entirely.)  But overall this is very broad and unclear.

Comment: To test the logic and functionality of the program, I want to send the application to a friend, so he could run it, and when you run it will connect to the database, but as the database is on my local server, then connect to it and perform authorization checks will be impossible, because the connection string refers to my PC. So here is the question, what do I need to do to fix this problem, as I understand you need to change the code will only be a connection string, and everything else is done through third-party utilities.

Comment: You definitely don't want to expose your database directly to the internet.  What ***I*** would do is build a Web API application to host on your local server and handle the interactions with the database.  Then the application that people use would integrate with that Web API, not directly with the database.  There are various other ways to approach it, but that's a very common and standard one.